# UICollectionView detailview scroll images

Tags: uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol, detailview

Please tell me an example of using UICollectionView with DetailView where i can scroll my images then.Maybe ho now link on github?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to achieve it by next steps:

1. I suppose you already bind your `UICollectionView` with the data source.
2. You need to add a selector to your image. It can be UIGestureRecognizer for example
3. If you add `UIGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView` you need to add method in your code for this recognizer that will open new `UIViewController`.
4. In new `UIViewController` you have to display your images. There are many already made photo viewers in the net. Just Google it.

You can check this [github](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser). Here is a photo browser like you are looking for.